# Cannot use terminal - dyld: Library not loaded /libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib

Tags: macos, terminal

Seemingly out of no where (used my computer yesterday and everything was fine), my terminal no longer works and I get the following error:

```
Last login: Thu Feb 13 21:48:00 on ttys001
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/libevent/lib/libevent-2.1.6.dylib
  Reason: image not found
[5]    2194 abort      

[Process completed]
```

Without the terminal I am a bit lost on how to fix this problem. I tried upgrading MacOS and that didn't work (currently on 10.15.3). I tried using the built in mac terminal and get the above error. Using iTerm2, it just immediately crashes. Same with Hyper terminal.

Comment: There's a problem with your installation of openssl: `libevent` references openssl's `libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib` which is not present. You're going to need to find a way to execute `brew switch openssl 1.0.2s`

Comment: That is the essence of my question. What can I do to gain back access of my command line so I can execute commands?

Comment: For one, you may try installing Python's IDLE and use it to run a script that'll execute commands like a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this, I used Microsoft Visual Studio Code, created a new file called "brew.sh" with this content:

```
/usr/local/bin/brew switch openssl 1.0.2s
```

and then installed the "code runner" extension, and used it to run the file.

I then uninstalled the "code runner" extension